# autocomplete issue with iScroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Autocomplete on my jQUeryMobile application. It works perfect. Now I'm trying to use iScroll.js to scroll through the list of looked up items. Here is what I'am doing,

http://jsfiddle.net/uXbKY/39/

The problem  is, iscroll is applying only for the first item of the suggestion box, where as I'm not able to scroll through entire list.Please help me if I'm missing anything in my code.Please help me to acheive this using iScoll.

I found one more way that we can use custom touch based scrollbar for autocomplete box
http://jsfiddle.net/uXbKY/2/
but there is a issue that, the custom scrollbar appears only for first search and it disappears from the suggastion box when list get refreshed, Please suggest me if we can fix this, because both options are fine for me for using my autocomplete in ipad and android.

or if anyone thinks there's a better way to do this than with iScroll and jScrollPane, you are wel-come I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is this: The iScroll must be applied to the **wrapper** of the scrolling area.

You seem to do it directly on the UL which has the id scroll

My guess is you'd have to put a wrapper around the UL and give it the id wrapper

I made a demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fluffy/rB8t3/):

If you type 1 letter, this will let you scroll through all words found containing that letter.

Comment: Thank you very much Fluffy but that is not giving smooth scrolling effect that we can get using cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/custom-scrollbar, and also it is not scrollable on ipad screen.. http://jsfiddle.net/uXbKY/2/ here I'm using autocomplete with jscrollpane but the the scrollbar disappears when suggastion box refreshes, so only for first search the custom scroller is applying, can you suggest me if we can modify this

Comment: I wouldn't go that route, try to stick to iScroll, I adjusted the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Fluffy/rB8t3/1/) with scrollbar support as described on the site, but I have no iPad so I can't tell. The reason why it probably doesn't scroll as smooth as the example is of jQueryUI

Comment: The answer above isn't working either, I'm getting back on this later. I find it interesting.

Comment: Well that's odd, this really doesn't seem to work combined with jQuery ui. I updated the fiddle with a working normal ul (uncomment 2 lines and comment 1 line) and the (strange) behavior whit a jQueryUI UL I'll check out the other example you posted.

Comment: This is not working. It seems like more people are searching for this answer but it isn't there. Best answer is found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878883/jquery-autocomplete-with-iscroll)

Comment: Thank you very much Fluffy, As i have tested the overflow works fine in iphone5.5 and in all ipads, but the problem is with android devices there we must implement touch scroll, Any how thank you very much for your interest...