# Jquery autocomplete with iScroll

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Autocomplete on my jQUeryMobile application. It works perfectly. Now I'm trying to use iScroll.js to scroll through the list of looked up items. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uXbKY/39/) is what I am doing,

The problem is that iscroll is applying only for the first item of the suggestion box, where as I'm not able to scroll through entire list .Please help me if I'm missing anything in my code. Please help me to acheive this using iScoll.

I [found](http://jsfiddle.net/uXbKY/2/) one more way that we can use custom touch based scrollbar for autocomplete box  but there is a issue that the custom scrollbar appears only for first search and it disappears from the suggastion box when list get refreshed, How can I fix this, because both options are fine for me for using my autocomplete in ipad and android.

If anyone thinks there's a better way to do this than with iScroll and jScrollPane I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest to abort the iScroll approach and use plain CSS for this:

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
    padding-right: 20px;
}
/* IE 6 doesn't support max-height
 * we use height instead, but this forces the menu to always be this tall
 */
* html .ui-autocomplete {
    height: 100px;
}
```

later on, if you insist, you can assign custom scrollbars with a little help from the [many](http://www.aplweb.co.uk/blog/js/scrollbars-v2/) [libraries](http://livepipe.net/control/scrollbar) [out](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) [there](http://www.areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo/) created for that purpose.

***Note:** the CSS snippet is ported from the official [jQuery UI AutoComplete reference](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source).*

Comment: Using custom JS scrollbars always look like a bad idea to me, and in a mobile environment can be probably worse.

Comment: @Terseus, have you read my answer, or the comment was meant to be posted on the question?

Comment: Yeah and I was just agreeding with your CSS approach.

Comment: Thank you Eliran , as i have tested the overflow of autocomplete, by setting your css, and it works fine in iphone and in all ipads, but the problem is with android devices there I must implement touch scroll, you can realize what i'm telling if you open my fiddles in android device,.. Thank you